# Setup Local Repository 18.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, dpkg, repository

I have created and build a bunch of custom programs/scripts and build them using dpkg-deb.  So I have a set of .deb files in a directory.

I do a `dpkg-scanpackages` to create the Packages.gz file.

I add `deb [trusted=yes] file:/opt/repo ./` to a `sources.list` file.

I perform an `apt-get update`, and I get lots of `Ign` messagaes about `Translation` and other files which doesn't exist.

When I then try to install a package, it finds it, and knows the dependencies, which are also custom and in the same folder, and says it cant find then dependency.

Any ideas?